# Twitter search api until and since parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, twitter

Preamble:

- Today is 17.10.2015
- Parameter `until` with date `From 2015-10-08 to 2015-10-17` is work just fine
- Parameter `until` with date less than `2015-10-08` does not work at all

What am i doing wrong? How can i get tweets in a date range (with more than a 10 days)?

Here is my code:

```
var params = {
    count: 3, 
    until: "2015-10-08", 
    from: "[any_random_user]"
};

$.ajax({
   url: twitterApi + "search/tweets.json",
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   data: params ,
   success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
   }
});
```

PS https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

PPS I am using 1.1 API version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.  As is mentioned on the page you linked to, the search service is limited for API users.

As [per the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets)

> Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day limit. In other words, no tweets will be found for a date older than one week.

You can download individual user's Tweets (up to 3,200 of them) if you are only interested in that user's Tweets.